# CSS/HTML floating div inheriting parent's width and not responding to defined width, what's wrong?

Tags: html, position, css-float, css

I'm new here and to HTML/CSS, so forgive me if I'm being incredibly dopey with this issue. I have searched for an answer to no avail and I finally admit defeat and ask...

I have two div boxes side by side in a container using float. No problmes there (i hope). I wish to split the right hand div box again. I thought it wouldn't be an issue, turns out I was wrong. I just cannot get the Include list (.includebox) to sit next to it's partner the Exclude list (.excludebox) inside .helpbox2

I've cut and pasted what I think is the pertinent code but I can always add more. The problem is live at www.exceptionalcvs.co.uk/help_cv_basics.html unless i've mucked around with it again - which I shall try my hardest to refrain from.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="margins">
      <div class="helpbox1">
        <h2>1. Introduction</h2>
        </p><p>
        <p>text here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="helpbox2">
        <h2>2. What do I put in my CV&#63;</h2>
        <p></p>
        <div class="includebox">Include list
          <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="excludebox">Exclude list
          <ul>
            <li>Passport number</li>
            <li>Driving license number</li>
            <li>Social Security number</li>
            <li></li>
            <li>Martial status</li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{width:960px;margin:0 auto}
.margins{margin-left:16px;margin-right:16px}
.helpbox2{position:relative;top:0;left:0;width:396px;float:right;padding-right:12px;padding-left:12px;padding-bottom:10px;border-bottom:1px solid #999;border-left:2px solid #999;border-top:2px solid #999;border-right:1px solid #999;background:#efe7ca;margin-left:5px}

.incudebox{position:relative;left:0px;right:0px;width:100px;float:left;margin:0px auto;}
.excludebox{position:relative;left:0px;right:0px;vertical-align:top;width:100px;float:right;margin:0px}
```

Apologies if the code is a bit messy. 
image of issue is here:
http://www.exceptionalcvs.co.uk/img/div_problem.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the l on `.includebox`

**Edit 2**

[Here's the same code simplified](http://jsfiddle.net/Nvmpg/2/), in a way that I'd do.

- Remove the `.margins` div, unnecessary
- Refactor your CSS so that you make style all `div`s in your second box the same, and make the only difference that one floats right
- Spread CSS rules onto separate lines, only make a rule one line if it has a single attribute
- Remove the `position:relative` and the `top` and `right`'s - again, unncessary
- I hope that helps :)

**Edit**
You also don't need anywhere near as much styling as you've got, these can all go as they're doing nothing (unless you have them for a reason I can't see in your example)

```
position:relative;left:0px;right:0px;;margin:0px auto;
```

**Also**

- Try to space out each CSS rule onto a new line, it makes it a lot easier to read
- When you use Stack Overflow, people really frequently use JSFiddle to demonstrate their issues. I used your code to help me, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nvmpg/)
- Try separating your elements with dashes, but always in lowercase, e.g. `.inside-box`
- *Welcome to Stack Overflow :)*

Comment: thanks...! screen blind I guess. Phew... thought I was going mad.

Comment: Thanks :D - BTW I'm just simplifying your code :), will update in a sec

Comment: Indeed... I was a bit hasty in compressing the files. This one wasn't supposed to have been compressed. Thanks again. I'm sure I'll be back!

Comment: And indeed re extra styling. I was mucking around with possibilities.

Comment: Oh when trying to fix your mysterious error? Hah! :) - it happens :P

Comment: yes, progressively worsening each minute after the first hour

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but you missed the 'L' on `.includebox` in your css file.

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SVEh9/

Comment: thanks...! screen blind I guess. Phew... thought I was going mad.